# Sequelize sum between two columns in model

Tags: sequelize.js

How can I create a query like this with sequelize ?

```
SELECT name, region, SUM(((COALESCE(base_income, 0) + COALESCE(user_taxes, 0))) AS total_sal FROM user GROUP BY name, region;
```

Comment: You may directly fire query, please have a look doc  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/

Comment: @ArifKhan Yep I can use raw query but that would be last resort when using a ORM. What would be the right way using Sequelize methods ?

Answer (score 8):

OK, so following is the solution for above RAW sql query.

```
  user.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'region', [sequelize.fn('SUM', (sequelize.fn('COALESCE', (sequelize.col('base_income')), 0), sequelize.literal('+'), sequelize.fn('COALESCE', (sequelize.col('user_taxes')), 0))), 'total_sal']],
  group: ['name', 'name']})
```

We have to use sequelize.literal inorder to place any operator between query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why, but this appears to return the sum of the last-provided column-- not the sum of both columns.

Comment: @defraggled did you ever figure out why that happens?

Comment: @boileau No sorry. I just checked my app code to find what implementation I landed on, but it seems I never ended up needing to do this anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it seems sequelize doesn't generate the correct SQL for that syntax. I ended up putting the whole query in sequelize.literal

Answer (score 7):

Although it is an old post, I ran to this now twice. So I'd like to share my solution:

```
user.findAll({ 
  attributes: [ 'name', 'region',
    [ sequelize.literal(
        'COALESCE(base_income, 0) + COALESCE(user_taxes, 0)'
      ), 'total_sal'
    ]
  ],
  group: ['name', 'name']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite not finding in [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/) the use as attributes. The [`sequelize.where`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-where) function can be a good **solution**, as it allows the use of [`sequelize.col`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-col) for case of associations in models.

```js
User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    'region',
    [
      Sequelize.fn(
        'SUM',
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('base_income'), '+', Sequelize.col('user_taxes'))
      ),
      'total_sal',
    ],
  ],
  group: ['name', 'region'],
})
```

Comment: Bom hack. This is good because it autoquotes the columns for us, which is mandatory e.g. in PostgreSQL when you have upper case chars, with literal you'd need double quotes in that case e.g. as in: `sequelize.literal('"baseIncome" + "userTaxes"')`. Still `.where` is so verbose, I'm tempted to just go with literal. What a shame...