# Updating with calculated values in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to run an update query on my model using the previous value in one of the fields.

This updates the model (row id=4) the 'seq' field to 5.

```
 Model.update({
        seq: 5
    },{
        where:{
            'id':4,

        }
    });
```

Now how do I update the model to the previous value stored in the 'seq' field + 5 ?

```
 Model.update({
            seq: 'seq' + 5
        },{
            where:{
                'id':4,

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use

```
Model.update(
  { seq: sequelize.literal('seq + 5') },
  { where: { id: model_id } }
);
```

Or you can use the `increment` [method](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-increment)

```
Model.increment('seq', { by: 5, where: { id: 'model_id' }});
```

Comment: Can this be used with upsert?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by using increment

```
 Model.increment(
        { seq: +5 },
        { where: { id: 4 } }
      );
```

and output:

```
UPDATE `Model` SET `seq`=`seq`+ 5 WHERE `id` = 4
```

Answer (score 7):

say you want to increment column aa by value 5 where gender is female

```
Users.increment('aa', { by: 5, where: { gender: 'female' } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some syntaxes that may be of interest, and slightly safer than using `literal`.

Given a table:

```
const Inverses = sequelize.define('Inverses',
  {
    myValue: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
await Inverses.sync({ force: true })
async function reset() {
  await sequelize.truncate({ cascade: true })
  await Inverses.create({ myValue: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two' });
  await Inverses.create({ myValue: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three' });
  await Inverses.create({ myValue: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five' });
}
```

Update to fixed myValue.

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: 0, },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  0, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse:  0, name: 'five'  },
```

Instead update to match another column:

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.col('myValue'), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  3, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse:  5, name: 'five'  },
```

Update to match another column with modification:

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.fn('1 + ', sequelize.col('myValue')), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  4, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse:  6, name: 'five'  },
```

A string function test.

```
await Inverses.update(
  { name: sequelize.fn('upper', sequelize.col('name')), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'THREE' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'FIVE'  },
```

Operator without parenthesis, e.g. col1 + col2. Possible with the "where" hack mentioned at: [Sequelize sum between two columns in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946586/sequelize-sum-between-two-columns-in-model/62493655#62493655) but that is so ugly I wonder if I should just use literal instead.

- [Sequelize sum between two columns in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946586/sequelize-sum-between-two-columns-in-model)
- [Addition and Subtraction Assignment Operator With Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778789/addition-and-subtraction-assignment-operator-with-sequelize)

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('myValue'), '*', sequelize.col('inverse')), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse:  -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  -9, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse: -25, name: 'five'  },
```

Equivalent literal version. We have to manually quote for PostgreSQL because of the upper case V.

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.literal('"myValue" * "inverse"'), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse:  -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  -9, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse: -25, name: 'five'  },
```

With a literal multiplier instead.

```
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('myValue'), '*', -2), },
  { where: { myValue: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
```

Outcome:

```
{ myValue: 2, inverse:  -2, name: 'two'   },
{ myValue: 3, inverse:  -6, name: 'three' },
{ myValue: 5, inverse: -10, name: 'five'  },
```

Tested on package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.14.0",
    "sql-formatter": "4.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

on Ubuntu 22.04, PostgreSQL 14.5.

[Runnable GitHub upstream with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/721dc3da15e0c7b92f6d3311d1b437c2490d7893/nodejs/sequelize/update.js).